keepassxc on more devices
I have a keepassxc database with passwords on my laptop with Lubuntu. I have a backup on flash drive via rsync.
I'd like to use the same database on my Android phone and Windows machine at work as well.
What is the most efficient and secure way to have a database synchronized (actual)
and utilize it on all of these devices?
Now, I have an idea of a cumbersome solution. To bring the flash with synchronized database every day to my work and have another copy on Android phone. What is a better solution?

You can keep the latest copy in the cloud if the data is not super sensitive. But your flash stick idea is probably the safest way.

Well the simplest and the safest solution is to have one server/service using ssh's sftp with which you will synchronize using rsync using the ssh keys or similar.  This place will be DB´s master.
I would generate ssh key pairs for each client.  Have them automatically loaded when you even when they contain password, which is safer.  You should have a different key for each device.
Before the opening/loading of KeePassXC just synchronize it to your client.  At certain periods, when you database is closed e.g. you lock your screen, you synchronize from client to the master server.  At the end of the session you create final synchronization where you put the latest KeePassXC database, then the device continues to shutdown.
You should always keep a backup in case the synchronization fails.  I would have the backup on each of the devices.
Edit for details:
On linux

openssh server and sftp
rsync
checking if the KeePassXC DB is open can be done via Gnome's secret-tool

secret-tool store --label='is_keepassxc_open' check status
Password: yes

# use this to check everytime
secret-tool lookup check status
yes # databse is unlocked

On Windows

I would use either msys2 or WSL2 and use openssh and rsync as on linux
I would try to integrate KeePassXC either with openssh or putty suite
I don't know how to check if KeePassXC is opened on Windows, maybe via PowerShell?

On Android

you need openssh server - I would try out SimpleSSHD or SSHelper
you can use rsync over MTP/usb - there are some tips for you there too
To open KeePassXC files you can, as you have written, use KeePassDX. There are others, but I'm using KPDX


I like this solution most. Could you please write the practical steps (with particular apps) how to achieve it? Will it work with Android KeePassDX as well? (I haven't found KeePassXC for Android).

@xralf I'll add the information when I'm at the computer.

@xralf is this enough or you need more?  If you need more please specify it in greater detail what you need.

Thanks a lot ...

There is another option. Syncthing which runs on Linux, Windows, Android or MacOS. You can keep an up to date version of anything on any or all your platforms automatically. Of course there is overhead. Seems to work well for keepassxc and you have lots of options.
The big win with this option, besides being automatic is that one solution works everywhere. It can be set to only work on your local network and you can even set it up to backup all the photos on you phone.
Syncthing has a GUI interface that makes it easy to setup for the most part and once you setup directories that you want to link between nodes all you have to do is put the files in those directories. Keepassxc will work directly from one of those directories so updates are transparent. If the Sync should fail on Keepassxc Syncthing will store the failed copy in the directory with a unique name and you can use Keepassxc to merge it at a later time.

With WebDAV you can read/write to a file on a internet server (ie. https://example.com/remote.php/dav/files/john.doe/mydatabase.kdbx). This way the online KDBX database-file on the online server is updated, and not a local file.
The Android App "Keepass2Android" and the keepass(.info) app supports WebDAV, KeepassXC doesn't.
For KeepassXC you need a down/upload client which keeps the local file and the online-server file in sync.
If you want to self-host your files and have a online-server, your might want to install nextcloud. Nextcloud keeps each db version after a change (backup).  Otherwise you can use google drive, onedrive, dropbox or similar. I think they support WebDAV and certainly have a sync client for all OSes available - if you don't mind hosing your password db there.
I'm not a security expert, but I think saving encrypted database-data over a encrypted TLS connection (https) is pretty secure. For work I'd rather use Keepass with WebDAV than KeepassXC with a local kdbx copy.
